# Variables jsp and java in same program

Tags: java, jsp

I'm programming with jsp and java. I need to pass a value between jsp and a method java but in the same program. I read documentation about this but I don't find a solution.Could I do this?.

My code is:

```
    if (form1.txtFamiliasSel.value=="<%=literales.getObject(TiposLiterales.TODOS)%>") {
         if (marca == "0") {
              marca = "0";
         }
         if (marca == "1") {
              marca = "D";
         }
         if (marca == "2") {
               marca = "C";
         }
   <%Familias lFamiliasSQL = new Familias(conn);
         int lCodFilial = 0;
         if (request.getParameter("cmbFilial") != null)
              lCodFilial = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cmbFilial"));
         ResultSet datosFam = lFamiliasSQL.doSelectLiteralesFamiliasFilial          
               (lCodFilial,marca);%>

       }
```

Answer (score 1):

Jsp is also Java code. They are not different. They are same. You don't need scriplets in between. Just remove those scriptlets.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this code without unwanted scriptlets :

```
if (form1.txtFamiliasSel.value==literales.getObject(TiposLiterales.TODOS)) {
    if (marca == "0") {
        marca = "0";
    }
    if (marca == "1") {
        marca = "D";
    }
    if (marca == "2") {
        marca = "C";
    }
    Familias lFamiliasSQL = new Familias(conn);
    int lCodFilial = 0;
    if (request.getParameter("cmbFilial") != null)
        lCodFilial = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("cmbFilial"));
    ResultSet datosFam = lFamiliasSQL.doSelectLiteralesFamiliasFilial          
    (lCodFilial,marca);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create an Object of java class which contain your mothod, in jsp file and call the method using that object.

eg java class:-

```
public class T4 {
    public String getResult(String st){

    return st;
    }
}
```

eg jsp file:-

```
<% 
// this is a very basic way to get java object, you can also create beans.
   T4 t4=new T4(); 
   out.print(t4.getResult);
%>
```